# Mapped function's arguments cannot be used in client-side operations

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image, geemap, sentinel

I am trying the below code to perform spectral dilation in GEE but gives me an error:

> spectral dilation: Layer error: A mapped function's arguments cannot
> be used in client-side operations

The code is pasted below:

```
var sentImage = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5))
//.filter(ee.Filter.lt('NOT_VEGETATED_PERCENTAGE', 70))
.filterDate("2016-01-02", "2020-12-30")
.filterBounds(rectangle);
var sentImage = sentImage.median().clip(rectangle);


var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12']; //Bands selected based on literature
var samp=sentImage.select(bands);
var no=ee.Number(10);
var spectral_dilation=samp.spectralDilation("sam",no);
Map.centerObject(spectral_dilation, 12);
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

See the [docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-spectraldilation) for `ee.Image.spectralDilation(metric, kernel, useCentroid)`

You need to pass it an `ee.Kernel` not a number.  See below. I've used a [circle kernel](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-kernel-circle) but there are others you can use.

e.g.

```
var sentImage = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 5))
//.filter(ee.Filter.lt('NOT_VEGETATED_PERCENTAGE', 70))
.filterDate("2016-01-02", "2020-12-30")
.filterBounds(rectangle);
var sentImage = sentImage.median().clip(rectangle);


var bands = ['B2','B3','B4','B8','B11','B12']; //Bands selected based on literature
var samp=sentImage.select(bands);
var no=ee.Kernel.circle(10);
var spectral_dilation=samp.spectralDilation("sam",no);
Map.centerObject(spectral_dilation,12);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some questions regarding this spectralDilation function which uses (sam) spectral angle mapper as matric, as for sam we have to provide the reference spectra, but in this function, there is no argument for reference spectra,,,, I mean where I have to give my reference spectra values to this function. your kind help needed in this regard